# Navigate through application that have windows shortcut

Tags: keyboard

<kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd> navigates through all open applications.
Some Apps can have no windows at all e.g. firefox, finder.
Is there a shortcut for navigating through only applications that have at least one window?

Comment: what you mean by "one window"?

Comment: @Am1 I believe he says that have “more than one"

Comment: Actually I think he means what he says... it's possible to have an application with no windows open and the app-switcher still shows it in the cmd-tab list.  Like if you close your last firefox window, firefox remains open, even though it has no actual "windows".  If you cmd-tab to firefox in this case, the only indication you will have that firefox is the 'active' application is the menubar.  Some other application's window, or the desktop, will appear to be the front-most window.

Answer (score 3):

The closest built-in option in OS X is to launch Expose which shows all open windows, then hit the tab key to cycle through all open apps.  It will still select those with no open windows, but is a quick alternative nonetheless.

Comment: the point being that you can visually see which apps have no open windows more easily than with cmd-tab.

Comment: nice one, but it's too much visual clutter for constant use.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean cycling through all open windows within a specific App?

<kbd>⌘tab</kbd> to switch between different apps and <kbd>⌘`</kbd>(backtick) to swap between windows in that app.

[Witch](http://manytricks.com/witch/) is an app that also does the trick more elegant if that’s what you want.